# Auto login of an PHP app and Bitnami Redmine

Tags: php, ruby, redmine, bitnami, redmine-plugins

Is there any possibilities that when I log in to my PHP app, I can automatically logged in to Bitnami Redmine and vice versa?

Comment: uh..... it's software. like [zombo.com](http://zombo.com) says, everything is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a session sharing...

I implemented the similar for WordPress, that is you need:

- Patch Rails to make them store sessions in JSON (not Ruby-specific Marshal).
  *I did this in my [RedPress](http://projects.andriylesyuk.com/project/redmine/redpress) plugin for Redmine - so you can use it.*
- Use Rails session in your PHP app.
  *I did this in my [WordMine](http://projects.andriylesyuk.com/project/wordpress/wordmine) plugin for WordPress - so you can use it as a sample.*